# mongodb inital load - building DBRef on the fly

Tags: mongodb, mongo-shell

I am trying to load initial data to mongodb using db.collections.insert. I have a case where I'll insert the town collection followed by zipcode collection. The zipcode collection refers to town collection. However when I write my script, I do not know the _id of the town. Would like to know how to build the reference on the fly.

In the e.g. below, I need the id of Mancehster town to be populated in the place of "unkown".

```
db.town.insert({name:"Manchester",state:{$ref:"state", $id:"CT"},status:"NOT-SUBSCRIBED"});

db.zipcode.insert({_id:"06040", town:{$ref:"town", $id:"unkown"}});
db.zipcode.insert({_id:"06041", town:{$ref:"town", $id:"unkown"}});
db.zipcode.insert({_id:"06042", town:{$ref:"town", $id:"unkown"}});
```

If there is different way to load my initial data rather than db.collections.insert, I'd like to know that too.

Comment: Could use batch insert or mongoimport/restore

Comment: @Sammaye That will not resolve my issue. I still need a way to find the _id dynamically.

Comment: Why don't you know the town reference? When you do an insert the default return is a document which contains the _id field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can generate your own ObjectId's. Adjusting your example,

```
var town_id = ObjectId()
db.town.insert({ "_id" : town_id, "name" : "Manchester", "state" : { "$ref" : "state", "$id" : "CT" }, "status" : "NOT-SUBSCRIBED" })

db.zipcode.insert({ "_id" : "06040", "town" : { "$ref" : "town", "$id" : town_id } })
db.zipcode.insert({ "_id" : "06041", "town" : { "$ref" : "town", "$id" : town_id } })
db.zipcode.insert({ "_id" : "06042", "town" : { "$ref" : "town", "$id" : town_id } })
```

Alternatively, since you seem to be using custom values for `_id` for `state` and `zipcode`, you can make up your own unique `_id` instead of generating one.

Though I don't know much about your use case, I also have to comment that I think you are doing too much referencing. DBRefs are pretty much never necessary. In this case, you know that `state` will reference the `state` collection, so why put that in the `state` field? Just make the value of the `state` field be the `_id` of the state document. Better yet, don't reference at all and just put `"state" : "CT"`. I doubt you really need a separate `state` collection. There's only 50 states and it's not like the names are going to change.

Comment: You are right. I'll remove the DBref for state. I would like to retain the state collection though. It helps me to get the list of states quickly.